# PHP glob() with few extensions

Tags: php, glob

I want to know when I have, in directory, any file with extension like : doc, docx, pdf, rtf.

My script is working for one extension

```
$ebook_filepath1 = glob($album_filepath . '*.txt') or array();
$ebook_count1 = count($ebook_filepath1);

if ($ebook_count1 != 0) {

echo "yes";

} else {

echo "no";

}
```

but for more that one not

```
$ebook_filepath1 = glob($album_filepath . '*.{txt,pdf,doc}') or array();
```

another problem is - how to use in this code the variable f.ex. named $extensions

```
$extensions = array('doc', 'docx', 'epub', 'mobi', 'pdf', 'rtf');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use **glob()** (you got that part right) with the **GLOB_BRACE** flag :

```
print_r(glob("*.{gz,zip}",GLOB_BRACE));
```

You could then easily build your string from your variable array with **implode()** :

```
$extensions = array('doc', 'docx', 'epub', 'mobi', 'pdf', 'rtf');
print_r(glob("*.{".implode(',',$extensions)."}",GLOB_BRACE));
```